# How to logically use PHP to display all possible values of a database table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

So I have created an interface that accepts input from a drop-down box..
[image]

Then displays the data from three different database tables in an HTML table with all entries that match the criteria.
[image]

The table is shown at the bottom of the above image.

My question is how do I use PHP, using loops or otherwise, to re-work my code and create a huge HTML page that goes through every single event? AKA I need to generate 126 tables:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to approach this. My initial thought was to use a loop and just put the code to generate **one single table** inside it, but I wouldn't know what to put the condition for it to stop, nor would I know how to cycle through the different options in the drop-down lists. I'm not asking anyone to create the code for me but rather point me in a direction of what logic to use.. after that, I can probably figure it out on my own. Thank you, everyone. :)

Below is my code, that I use to generate each table, with annotations in comment form:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dbhost     = "localhost"; //logs into my localhost server
$dbname     = "sportsDay";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "...";

$year=$_POST['Year'];  //gets variables from the drop-downs in the form displayed above
$gender=$_POST['Gender']; 
$event=$_POST['Event']; 

$result[]=0;
try
{

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");

    $sql = "SELECT Students.lName, Students.fName, Students.house 
    FROM Entries INNER JOIN Events ON Entries.ev1ID = Events.ID   
    JOIN Students ON Students.stID = Entries.stID
    WHERE (Entries.ev1ID = :event or Entries.ev2ID = :event2) and (Students.year = :year) 
    AND (Students.gender = :gender)
    ORDER BY Students.house ASC"; 
  //my SQL code that matches up the values from the drop-downs to the values in the database tables

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':event', $event);
    $stmt->bindValue(':event2', $event);
    $stmt->bindValue(':year', $year);
    $stmt->bindValue(':gender', $gender);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
     ?>
     <html>
     <body>
     <?php if ($count > 0): ?> //checks to see if there are results. if there are results, it displays them:
    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>House</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { 
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['fName']. ' '.$row['lName'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['house'] ?></td> <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
<?php else: echo "No results." ?> //if not, it displays that there are no results.
<?php endif ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: So the post was a lot to take in, but are you trying to generate lots of tables at once? That's what I gained from reading the bottom part?

Comment: @Jek yes, basically I am trying to generate lots of tables at once. I'm so sorry that it was unclear, I will edit the post for clarity.

Comment: @Jek does it make sense now?

Comment: Compared to a lot of SO posts I see, you're doing a lot of things correctly here: You have error reporting, you have the correct character set, you have PDO you're using Object database interfacing. You're using try/catch blocks... Good job so far :)

Comment: @Martin you have no idea how much that means to me, sir. thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have your code to generate *one* table, you are correct that you can use that to generate *all* of them.

All you need to do is to cycle through all possibilities your form provides.

You must have a list of possible options in order to build the HTML form, just use these option lists in a nested foreach loop.

```
foreach ($event as $e) {
  foreach ($gender as $g) {
    foreach ($year as $y) {
      // Use $e, $g and $y for your query and table construction.
      $sql = ...; // Query stays the same.

      $stmt->bindValue(':event', $e);
      $stmt->bindValue(':event2', $e);
      $stmt->bindValue(':year', $y);
      $stmt->bindValue(':gender', $g);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the full example according to the code you provided:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dbhost     = "localhost"; //logs into my localhost server
$dbname     = "sportsDay";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "...";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");

?>
<html>
<body>
<?php

// Lists of possible DB values
$event = array("100m", "100m relay", "High Jump", ...); // a list of all events
$gender = array("F", "M"); // a list of all genders
$year = array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12); // a list of all classes

foreach ($event as $e) {
  foreach ($gender as $g) {
    foreach ($year as $y) {

      $result[] = 0;
      try {
          $sql = "SELECT Students.lName, Students.fName, Students.house 
          FROM Entries INNER JOIN Events ON Entries.ev1ID = Events.ID   
          JOIN Students ON Students.stID = Entries.stID
          WHERE (Entries.ev1ID = :event or Entries.ev2ID = :event2) and (Students.year = :year) 
          AND (Students.gender = :gender)
          ORDER BY Students.house ASC"; 

          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

          $stmt->bindValue(':event', $e);
          $stmt->bindValue(':event2', $e);
          $stmt->bindValue(':year', $y);
          $stmt->bindValue(':gender', $g);

          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
          $count = $stmt->rowCount();
      }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
      }

     if ($count > 0) {
?>
    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>House</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { 
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['fName']. ' '.$row['lName'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['house'] ?></td> <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

<?php 
      }
      else {
        echo "No results for $e ($g, $y).";
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I understand the reasoning behind this foreach() method. However I'm very confused as to how to implement this into the form's action: "$year=$_POST['Year']; 
$gender=$_POST['Gender']; 
$event=$_POST['Event']; " I have to change this part, right?

Comment: You do not need the form anymore since all possibilities (tables) will be printed. You could just use the variables `$e $g and $y` in your database query. See the updated answer.

Comment: Umm.. http://pastebin.com/jWyMjJku like this? I'm very confused, i'm sorry-- it seems I may be missing something major...

Comment: Basically yes. Did you try it? The table declaration of your result should be within the loop as well. Looks good to me at first glance.

Comment: yes, i did try it, and no, it did not work :\ that's why i asked. i got the following errors; "Notice: Undefined variable: event in {dir} on line 18" and "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in {dir} on line 18". line 18 is as follows: "foreach ($event as $e) {" but shouldnt i get an error for each of the foreach() methods then?

Comment: See updated answer for a full example according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your db structure. Using a Left join, I was able to retrieve all the data you need sorted by event ID.

My database recreation:

Students table

```
+------+---------+-----------+-------+
| stID | fName   | lName     | house |
+------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    1 | Nadir   | Roman     | east  |
|    2 | Jesus   | Lopez     | west  |
|    3 | Ioannis | Chalkadis | west  |
|    4 | Adry    | Pepes     | east  |
|    5 | David   | Caretas   | west  |
+------+---------+-----------+-------+
```

Events table

```
+----+-----------+---------------+
| ID | name      | location      |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | 100m      | Track         |
|  2 | 400m      | Track         |
|  3 | High Jump | High Jump Pit |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

Scores table

```
+------+-------+-------+
| stID | ev1ID | ev2ID |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |     1 |     2 |
|    2 |     2 |     3 |
|    3 |     1 |     3 |
|    4 |     1 |     2 |
|    5 |     1 |     3 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

THe query:

```
mysql> SELECT Events.ID, Events.name, location, Scores.stID, fName, lName, house FROM Scores LEFT JOIN (Students, Events) ON (Students.stID = Scores.stID AND (Events.ID = Scores.ev1ID OR Events.ID = Scores.ev2ID)) ORDER BY ID;
```

And the output is:

```
+------+-----------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+-------+
| ID   | name      | location      | stID | fName   | lName     | house |
+------+-----------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    1 | 100m      | Track         |    1 | Nadir   | Roman     | east  |
|    1 | 100m      | Track         |    5 | David   | Caretas   | west  |
|    1 | 100m      | Track         |    4 | Adry    | Pepes     | east  |
|    1 | 100m      | Track         |    3 | Ioannis | Chalkadis | west  |
|    2 | 400m      | Track         |    2 | Jesus   | Lopez     | west  |
|    2 | 400m      | Track         |    1 | Nadir   | Roman     | east  |
|    2 | 400m      | Track         |    4 | Adry    | Pepes     | east  |
|    3 | High Jump | High Jump Pit |    2 | Jesus   | Lopez     | west  |
|    3 | High Jump | High Jump Pit |    5 | David   | Caretas   | west  |
|    3 | High Jump | High Jump Pit |    3 | Ioannis | Chalkadis | west  |
+------+-----------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+-------+
```

You can split this output into different arrays, 1 per event:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$mappedEvents = [];

array_map(function($entry)
{
    if(!isset($mappedEvents[$entry['ID']]))
    {
       $mappedEvents[$entry['ID']] = [];
    }
    $mappedEvents[$entry['ID'][] = $entry;
}, $result);

foreach($mappedEvents as $eventID => $data)
{
        // $eventID = event ID
        // $data = Array with all info about the event (students, location, etc..)
}
```

Comment: hello good sir. Scores is not a table in the database :) it is simply an external part of the table, because the system i'm creating is meant to create pages that can be printed out so that the pages can be written on by hand, aka the blank column of the table is meant to be blank so it can be filled in in person. in addition, may i ask for a further explanation of your answer?  i don't understand how it answers my question because i'm very inexperienced in PHP and im afraid i may have misunderstood your response. thank you nadir :)

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your question. You are trying to build a html page that list a table for each Event, and on each table you should display information about the students that are participating on them, is that right?

Comment: yes. :) but I need a separate table for each event, it seems that your output is one single table?

Comment: I added an example at the bottom to show how you can split the output and get 1 array per event.